# Liskov substitution principle and proper way to use inherited classes

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, architecture, liskov-substitution-principle

I have some handler ("controller") classes and they can process items in some way:

```
interface IHandler
{
    public function execute(Item $item);
}

class FirstHandler implements IHandler
{
    public function execute(Item $item) { echo $item->getTitle(); }
}

class SecondHandler implements IHandler
{
    public function execute(Item $item) { echo $item->getId() . $item->getTitle(); }
}

class Item
{
    public function getId() { return rand(); }
    public function getTitle() { return 'title at ' . time(); }
}
```

But then I need to add some new functionality in child Item class:

```
class NewItem extends Item
{
    public function getAuthor() { return 'author ' . rand(); }
}
```

and use it in SecondHandler

```
class SecondHandler implements IHandler
{
    public function execute(Item $item) { printf('%d %s, author %s', $item->getId(), $item->getTitle(), $item->getAuthor()); }
}
```

But `Item` class actually has not `getAuthor` method. And, if I try to change signature of accept method in `SecondHandler` class, I will catch `E_STRICT` error about declaration compatibility. And, of course, it's sort of LSP violation.

How can I fix this problem? Do I need two interfaces, for example, `INewHandler` and `IHandler`, with different signatures of `execute` method? But it's some sort of code duplicates.

Also, I cannot use `__constructor(Item $item)` and `__construct(NewItem $item)`  in handlers (and `execute` method without arguments), which will be seen like a better solution: they must be immutable and only single instance of every strategy allowed in application lifecycle.

Comment: I believe using less generic names in the example would help us identify and solve the problem better.

Comment: Any ideas? You have "handler" class and simple "DTO" class (Doctrine entity, Yii ActiveRecord, whatever else)

Comment: If [Strategy is not a reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134270/liskov-substitution-principle-and-proper-way-to-use-inherited-classes?noredirect=1#comment56106674_34180134) to the [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), do not put a red herring in front of us. This looks pretty much like Strategy.

Comment: How exactly do the items relate to each other? Is inheritance really necessary? Why not composition? If given more descriptive names (implying a more specific scenario), we could judge better.

Comment: Edited. Items are actually related, because I use Class table inheritance of Doctrine and also they have shared methods (getId, getTitle, etc.)

Comment: Shared methods are not a good reason to introduce inheritance. Both people and books can have IDs and titles and I guess inheritance does not seem right in either way, nor does a common ancestor make sense.

Comment: Yes, "it depends". In my case I use http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html, so I really need to use inheritance.
Okay, lets think I don't need it. Then how can I to use type hinting in my handlers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98202/discussion-between-palec-and-guy-fawkes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered by yourself, the type hinting implementation of PHP has a lot limitations that make scenarios, like the one described by you, harder than they should be. In other typed languages like Java and Swift your implementation is absolutely licit.

After some thinking on your question I came to the solution presented by [Félix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34137779/1750243) but I consider it too much over engineered compared to the problem.

My answer to your question is not a solution but an advice that I give to you after years of development with PHP:

**Give up with type hinting in PHP and develop like it should be... in a dynamic way**.

PHP is more similar to Ruby/Python/JavaScript than Java/C++, and trying to copy 1 to 1 from static typed languages translates in forced and convolute implementations.

The solution to your implementation problem is easy, so don't over complicate it and keep it easy as it should be (KISS principle).

Declare the methods' arguments without the type and implement a check where you really need (for example throwing an exception).

```
interface IStrategy
{
    public function execute($item);
}

class FirstStrategy implements IStrategy
{
    public function execute($item) {
        echo $item->getTitle();
    }
}

class SecondStrategy implements IStrategy
{
    public function execute($item) {
        // execute(NewItem $item) is identical to this check.
        if (! $item instanceof NewItem) {
            throw new Exception('$item must be an instance of NewItem');
        }
        echo $item->getAuthor();
    }
}

class Item
{
    public function getId() { return rand(); }
    public function getTitle() { return 'title at ' . time(); }
}

class NewItem extends Item
{
    public function getAuthor() { return 'author ' . rand(); }
}
```

#### Again, don't think in Java but follow as much as possible the duck typing way.

When possible, try to don't strictly force the type of the parameters but adapt the behavior of the code based on the available interfaces (Duck Typing).

```
class SecondStrategy implements IStrategy
{
    public function execute($item) {
        $message = $item->getTitle();

        // PHP 5 interface availability check.
        if (is_callable([$item, 'getAuthor'])) {
            $message .= ' ' . $item->getAuthor();
        }

        // With PHP 7 is even better.
        // try {
        //     $message .= ' ' . $item->getAuthor();
        // } catch (Error $e) {}

        echo $message;
    }
}
```

I hope to have helped you. ^_^

Comment: Yes, I think solution with instanceof checking is much more simple. In Java I can use child class hinting instead of parent class?

Comment: Java supports method overloading, so you can implement two methods:
- public void execute(Item item) {}
- public void execute(NewItem item) {}
The first one satisfies the interface definition, the second one is your extension to the interface.

Comment: For completeness, if you want to use the child class hinting instead of the overloading of the "execute()" method, you can. Simply reimplement your code using Java generics.

Comment: This solution is fine when this is the only one place where you need code like this. And in terms of quality/efforts, I would go with it.

But if we imagine you'll need similar if-statements in 100 places it definitely tells us there is something wrong with your design.

Comment: You are checking the type for `NewItem` but why not for `Item` (in `FirstStrategy`)?

Comment: Because in the question it's assumed that by default methods accept an `Item`; only `SecondStrategy` implements a "custom" behavior. Of course, a check could be implemented in every method, but I consider it superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Both @daniele-orlando and @ihor-burlachenko made valid points.
Consider following approach for method overloading, which is kind of a compromise and should scale well:

```
interface IHandler
{
    /**
     * @param $item Item|NewItem
     */
    public function execute($item);

    // protected function executeItem(Item $item);
    // protected function executeNewItem(NewItem $item);    
}

trait IHandlerTrait
{   
    public function execute($item) 
    {
        switch(true) {
            case $item instanceof Item:
                return $this->executeItem($item);
            case $item instanceof NewItem:
                return $this->executeNewItem($item);
            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported parameter type " . get_class($item));
        }
    }

    protected function executeItem(Item $item)
    {
        throw new \LogicException(__CLASS__ . " cannot handle execute() for type Item");
    }

    protected function executeNewItem(NewItem $item)
    {
        throw new \LogicException(__CLASS__ . " cannot handle execute() for type NewItem");
    }
}

class FirstHandler implements IHandler
{
    use IIHandlerTrait;

    protected function executeItem(Item $item) { echo $item->getTitle(); }
}

class SecondHandler implements IHandler
{
    use IIHandlerTrait;

    // only if SecondHandler still need to support `Item` for backward compatibility
    protected function executeItem(Item $item) { echo $item->getId() . $item->  getTitle(); }

    protected function executeNewItem(NewItem $item) { printf('%d %s, author    %s', $item->getId(), $item->getTitle(), $item->getAuthor()); }
}
```

Comment: I guess, you wanted to type `
    protected function executeNewItem(NewItem $item);`

Comment: You have to rollback your changes. There is no method visibility in an interface, they are all public ;)

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko, thanks. Lesson learned! That's shame there is now way to expose private methods anywhere but abstract class tho. The best thing I can think of is to leave them as comments =(

Comment: Well, the interface user shouldn't know about details of implementation so it is the best just to leave them the trait.

Comment: Fair enough. It is more for developers who will write new implementation of the interface. Let's put it this way, I would appreciate if developers left such comment right in the interface, if I end up maintaining their code. A link between the trait and the interface is quite elusive.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use Strategy pattern here?

It looks, like the strategy's action here depends on the type of the element it processes. And [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern might apply here as well in this case.

Comment: Strategy is just a class name, not reference to design pattern.

Comment: @GuyFawkes Whatever ;) Is my suggestion invalid for your case?

Comment: May be it is valid :) Can you provide some example which will resolve LSP violation problem?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you appear to want to execute an extensible data record (Item and NewItem).  Consider instead *executing* some pluggable *behaviour* (implemented via an interface).

It's hard from your writing to guess what that behavior would be, because (New)Item is just a glorified data structure in the example you provide.

Comment: I think in terms of Doctrine entities (which is actually Items) it's wrong to add some logic to them. What do you mean by pluggable behaviour?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about "Doctrine entities" or the implementation of OO in (what I now gather is) PHP. Typically in an OO language that supports them, one uses interfaces to provide polymorphism between objects that have a common behavior - not state.

Comment: For example, it's not a good idea to have some logic in DTO classes (simple classes only for values exchange between other classes)

Comment: I am a proponent of writing object oriented code, rather than a procedural approach that has code acting on data, especially to model a complex problem or domain into code.  Sorry, I don't think I can help in this instance.

Comment: Cannot understand why DTO is not a part of "OOP-written" code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work/manipulate with object in another object, you could/should use interfaces.

```
interface IStrategy
{
    public function execute(ItemInterface $item);
}

interface ItemInterface 
{
   public function getTitle();
   .....
}
```

If you want to extend public functionality of the (New)Item class you can make new interface for newItem

```
interface NewItemInterface extends ItemInterface 
{
...
}

class SecondStrategy implements IStrategy
{
    public function execute(NewItemInterface $item) 
    { .... }
}
```

Or you can use some instance checks as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If your inheritance and suggestion that SecondHandler should handle both Item and NewItem were correct in the first place, then you should be able to hide this functionality behind the common interface. From your examples, it might be called toString() which might be a part the Item interface.

Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your design initially. And you have to change your inheritance or the way you handle items. Or something else we don't know about.

Also, I don't know why you need DTO but it seems there is some misunderstanding of Doctrine. Doctrine is an ORM and it solves your persistence problem. It adds limitations on how you communicate with your storage introducing repositories, but it doesn't define your domain logic.

Comment: I save Item after its processing by all Handlers. And I haven't limitations of Doctrine, I have limitations of "universal pipeline processing" of items.

Comment: If all items have to be processed by all handlers and each handler acts the same on each item and your inheritance is correct then you should be able to hide the class-specific functionality behind the common interface.


It is not clear for me why you decided that Doctrine entities should be DTO. But assuming that these have to be DTOs you still have the corresponding models with the corresponding inheritance hierarchy. In this case you just hide this class-specific functionality behind the common interface of your models and convert DTOs to models in your handlers to call it.

Comment: Yes, I think I need extra logic level. I don't like to have another logic then "set/get" in Doctrine entities. May be some programmers use entities as "fat models", but I prefer "thin controller, thin model and fat service layer"

Comment: Well, you answered your own question. Still my concern is that with this inheritance hierarchy your services might contain if-statements or they can be hidden behind some behavioural pattern (which still seems to me like an engineering solution to problems in domain design). I recommend you to have a look at DDD. It might take your focus away from thin/fat view to a domain-driven approach which suits very well with OOP paradigm.

Comment: Also, have a look at Martin Fowler's opinion about local DTOs: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html

Comment: I think DDD is very common phrase, sort of buzz-word. You still have logic which implements parts of your domain. My question is how to properly implement this "low-level" part of domain.

Comment: When I say DDD I mean Eric Evans and his book: http://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215

Answer (score 0):

As per the Interface segregation please find some solution.

```

```
# based on interface segrigation.

interface BasicInfo
{
    public function getId();
    public function getTitle();
}

interface AuthorInfo
{
    public function getAuthor();
}

interface IHandler
{
    public function execute(Item $item);
}

class FirstHandler implements IHandler
{
    public function execute(Item $item) { echo $item->getTitle(); }
}

class SecondHandler implements IHandler
{
    public function execute(Item $item) { echo $item->getId() . $item->getTitle(); }
}

class Item implements BasicInfo
{
    public function getId() { return rand(); }
    public function getTitle() { return 'title at ' . time(); }
}

class Item2 extends Item implements AuthorInfo
{
    public function getAuthor() { return 'author ' . rand(); }
}
```

But I think you should not kept the dependency of the Item class. you should write some duplicated code to keep the class pluggable/independent. So the Open/close principle should also there.